# Bash error: Nesting 'if .. elif' inside 'for .. in' construct

Tags: bash

When I run the code below:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `more extensions.txt` do 
    if  grep '[219..223]' ${line:96:4} ; then
        ...
    else
        ...
    fi
done
```

I keep getting the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'if'
```

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing either a semicolon or a newline before `do`.

Both of the following scripts will work.

---

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `more extensions.txt` ; do
        if  grep '[219..223]' ${line:96:4} ; then
                echo "1"
        else
                echo "2"
        fi
done
```

---

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `more extensions.txt`
do
        if  grep '[219..223]' ${line:96:4} ; then
                echo "1"
        else
                echo "2"
        fi
done
```

---

> **Note:** Your script is also missing a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). It's better practice to include one in the first line of your script.
>
> This allows you to call your script using `./script.sh` if the file's executable bit is set, in addition to `sh script.sh` or `bash script.sh`